# Multiple HTML tables in single email with header and table

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I need to send an alert with multiple HTML tables in single email. I am stuck in formatting the email. I have 11 HTML tables, that need to be attached in single email and before every HTML table I need to add title. As we don't have IS HTML option anymore in Logic apps, I am confused on how to format the email

Comment: Please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the feature "**IsHTML**" has been removed from "**Send email**" action in logic app. If you want to send html content in the body of email, you need to build the HTML content in an action before send the email. Do it like below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks